# How to add custom jquery to foundation

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, zepto

I'm new to Zurb Foundation framework. I'm trying to include a custom jquery file, but it doesn't work. I'm including the custom file below foundation scripts, and contains a simple click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select-all').on('click', function(e){ 
    $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
});
});
```

When I include jquery only instead of zepto, the custom code now works but all foundation scripts no longer work.

Any help?

Comment: Are you calling '$(document).foundation();' anywhere on your page?

Comment: yes I have this before the closing body tag:
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
    $(document).foundationAccordion();
  </script>

Comment: Remove the second call to Foundation Accordion. The first call will initialize all Foundation plugins. Use the second call only if you want to initialize plugins on an individual basis.